# PHP curl_setopt Not Working Properly?

Tags: php

This is my url when i run that url directly to browser that work properly.

```
http://domainname.com/helloworld/dimond/add?name=abcd&price=1860
```

this url is run properly but i send request using curl_setopt that is not working. my code like.

```
$data="?name=$products_name&price=$fltPrice";
$url = 'http://domain.com/helloworld/dimond/add'.$data;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$myfile = curl_exec($ch);
```

Plase Help.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to send it via POST instead of GET ?

Comment: What's not workign exactly ?

Comment: @shivan yes i send data as a post.

Comment: Maybe you can try curl_error() for debugging http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: But you are now sending via GET .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a POST request via cURL, use the following:

```
$data="?name=$products_name&price=$fltPrice";
$url = 'http://domain.com/helloworld/dimond/add';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```